# InfoWindow appears minimum size no matter what

Tags: javascript, google-maps

There are several posts relating to this topic here but I've applied what seemed relevant on everything I read:

**CSS**

```
.infoWindow {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
}
```

**Create InfoWindow and assign to marker**

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div class="infoWindow">Test</div>',
    maxWidth: 100
});

infowindow.open(map,test);
```

**Result**

[image]

As you can see the InfoWindow appears at minimum size and no text is visible, this is also the case if I strip out the `<div>` tag and all styling parameters and just try to display "Test".

[You can check the live site yourself here (hover over top right of screen to display map)](http://rlcoaching.com/albaraka/)

**Why does the InfoWindow insist on staying at minimum size?**

**EDIT: Turns out this problem only happens on a "reload", IE: when page is cached. Every time I clear the cache it works fine, but if I reload page without clearing cache it displays like in the picture above.
Tried on Firefox & Chrome, OSX**

Comment: Setting the height and width of the div inside the infowindow inline has worked for me.

Comment: Your live site works for me, the infowindow doesn't look like your picture, looks like it might be 90px x 90px, perhaps you have an old version stuck in your browser cache.

Comment: @geocodezip Yes I just realised that when I clear cache and reload page it appears fine. If I resize window and reload page it displays as it does in the image in my post. I now think it's a glitch caused by resizing window. I have to clear the cache each time to get it to display properly.

Comment: @geocodezip Yes I just realised that when I clear cache and reload page it appears fine. If reload page it displays as it does in the image in my post. I have to clear the cache each time to get it to display properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution putting the content inside a variable.

```
var content='<div class="infoWindow">Test</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:content,
    maxWidth: 100
});
```

in the past I had similar problem and this worked.

**update**

I have removed some options from `Infowindow` according to [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#add) documentation.

> > The InfoWindowOptions object literal contains the following fields: 
> >     1)content  
> >   2)position 
> >  3)maxWidth

**update 2**

set `min-height`, `min-width` css property to your `.infoWindow` class

**update 3**

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575796/force-google-infowindow-to-redraw-itself-or-refresh-its-content) stack question for your new problem

Comment: That shouldn't matter.  BTW, the infowindow does not have width, height or maxHeight options... (it does have a maxWidth, but that doesn't seem relevant to the issue).

Comment: look at this documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#add. I don't see `width`,`heigh`t and `maxHeight` parameters. Did you add an overload for these elements?

Comment: @geocodezip I didn't see your comment. Did you try to remove that options?

Comment: Thanks for the help, doesn't work though, infowindow is still min. size

Comment: which browser are you using? I have differents behaviors in differents browser with your code

Comment: add `min-width:90px` to your css for `infoWindow` class

Comment: just realised weird thing, if I clear the cash and view the page it works 1st time only. Consequent refreshes of the page make the infowindow appear min size. Is there a way to refresh the infoWindow? I think it may be resizes that trigger that prob

Comment: I don't understand which is the problem now... I see that works

Comment: @faby Sorry I think I'm confusing you... I've updated my main post. Basically when page is cached it displays as it does in the picture above (bugged up). If I clear cache and reload page it works fine. Have you tried reloading my page once it's cached?

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna give you the point. The trick is to `infowindow.open(map,albaraka);` to refresh the infowindow every time you change anything about the map like the position of it in document