# Access InfoWindow from angular google map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I am using google maps via angularJS (using [angular-google-map](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps))

I have a marker with an InfoWindow which works fine except on iOS. When I rotate the device, the google map API doesn't seem to calculate the size well and the infoWindow is too small for its content. I reckon this is the same bug as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619738/infowindow-appears-minimum-size-no-matter-what?lq=1)

So I have been trying to access the InfoWindow object to close it and open it again to force google to redraw/recalculate but couldn't find a way to access it. 
I can access the google.maps.Map object by using  *$scope.map.control.getGMap()* in angular but can't access the InfoWindow. I can see a getGWindows in  Window.prototype but no idea how to access it from the map. I can access the markers as well but they don't have a reference to their infowindow.

Here is the way I create the marker in case it can be of any help:

```
var marker = {
    id: obj.id,
    name: obj.name,
    latitude: obj.lat,
    longitude: obj.lng,
    address: obj.address,
    suburbCity: obj.suburbCity,
    state: obj.state,
    postcodeZip: obj.postcodeZip,
    icon: "xxx.png"),
    options: {
        labelContent: obj.name,
        labelClass: "none",
        labelAnchor:"25 0", 
        opacity: 0.25,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        visible: true
    },
    templateurl:'markerwindow.tpl.html',
    templateparameter: data,
    closeClick: function() {
        marker.options.visible = false;
        return $scope.$apply();
    },
    onClicked: function() {
        navigateToMarkerOnMap(marker);
    }
};

$scope.map.markers.push(marker);


function navigateToMarkerOnMap(marker) {
    $scope.selected.options.visible = false;
    $scope.selected = marker;
    $scope.selected.options.visible = true;
}
```

Comment: What device is it that has the issue? Is it a particular device every time or have you tested on multiple iOS devices and it doesn't work on all?

Comment: Yes any IOS device I tried was having that issue and happening every time.

Comment: With my knowledge in google-maps the only why to obtain the info instance it's storing on array in your javascript, so if the directive doesn't return that ( I think it not ) that won't be possible, even getting by id or anything, sorry, try sending your question on their comunity https://plus.google.com/communities/101653511105172739950?utm_source=websiten&utm_medium=link maybe they have this possibility or it could be a future

Comment: Try resizing map with `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')`. It would resize the info window too, most likely. Just as a workaround and yes you could report the issue as well. Here's another link: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/